# Eureka client should not be enabled in docker image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I have this test Spring Boot project running in Kubernetes:

https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup.git

When I run the project into Intelij or locally using `java -jar mockup.jar` I have the project running as a Eureka server. Log file:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.6.15)

2024-01-21 00:21:02.177  INFO 3608 --- [           main] com.mockup.mockup.MockupApplication      : Starting MockupApplication using Java 17 on DESKTOP-BKOOSAD with PID 3608 (C:\Users\plte1219\Desktop\CJM\atlas_in_progress\test\trash\11111111111111111111111\prepare\mockup\build\classes\java\main started by plte1219 in C:\Users\plte1219\Desktop\CJM\atlas_in_progress\test\trash\11111111111111111111111\prepare\mockup)
2024-01-21 00:21:02.179  INFO 3608 --- [           main] com.mockup.mockup.MockupApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-01-21 00:21:03.068  INFO 3608 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=8fc5af37-d92d-3156-beb3-e41828073dcc
2024-01-21 00:21:03.354  INFO 3608 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8761 (http)
2024-01-21 00:21:03.364  INFO 3608 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-01-21 00:21:03.364  INFO 3608 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.75]
2024-01-21 00:21:03.491  INFO 3608 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-01-21 00:21:03.491  INFO 3608 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1269 ms
2024-01-21 00:21:05.105  INFO 3608 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2024-01-21 00:21:06.546  INFO 3608 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2024-01-21 00:21:06.554  INFO 3608 --- [           main] DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration : Eureka HTTP Client uses Jersey
2024-01-21 00:21:06.617  WARN 3608 --- [           main] iguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger : Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. While this cache implementation is useful for development and tests, it's recommended to use Caffeine cache in production.You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath.
2024-01-21 00:21:06.625  INFO 3608 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2024-01-21 00:21:06.708  INFO 3608 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2024-01-21 00:21:06.738  INFO 3608 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2024-01-21 00:21:06.739  INFO 3608 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2024-01-21 00:21:06.748  INFO 3608 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1705789266747 with initial instances count: 0
2024-01-21 00:21:06.752  INFO 3608 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application MOCKUP with eureka with status UP
2024-01-21 00:21:06.774  INFO 3608 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http) with context path ''
2024-01-21 00:21:06.775  INFO 3608 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8761
2024-01-21 00:21:07.882  INFO 3608 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2024-01-21 00:21:07.936  INFO 3608 --- [           main] com.mockup.mockup.MockupApplication      : Started MockupApplication in 7.371 seconds (JVM running for 8.087)
Test message loaded from default application.yml file
2024-01-21 00:21:08.085  INFO 3608 --- [2)-192.168.56.1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-01-21 00:21:08.085  INFO 3608 --- [2)-192.168.56.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-01-21 00:21:08.087  INFO 3608 --- [2)-192.168.56.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
```

But when I run the project as a Pod into Kubernetes I get this output:

```
root@node1:~# kubectl logs mockup-69c7855f5b-8phdb

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.6.15)

2024-01-20 22:25:46.620  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.mockup.mockup.MockupApplication      : Starting MockupApplication using Java 21-ea on mockup-69c7855f5b-8phdb with PID 1 (/mockup.jar started by ? in /)
2024-01-20 22:25:46.629  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.mockup.mockup.MockupApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-01-20 22:26:26.319  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=7fef07ea-f79b-3615-9503-2ec56a0b4b4e
2024-01-20 22:26:37.421  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2024-01-20 22:26:37.718  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-01-20 22:26:37.719  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.75]
2024-01-20 22:26:40.421  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-01-20 22:26:40.422  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 52100 ms
2024-01-20 22:27:24.220  INFO 1 --- [           main] DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration : Eureka HTTP Client uses Jersey
2024-01-20 22:27:27.624  WARN 1 --- [           main] iguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger : Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. While this cache implementation is useful for development and tests, it's recommended to use Caffeine cache in production.You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath.
2024-01-20 22:27:28.121  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2024-01-20 22:27:29.923  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2024-01-20 22:27:36.425  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2024-01-20 22:27:41.724  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2024-01-20 22:27:41.725  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2024-01-20 22:27:49.720  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2024-01-20 22:27:49.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2024-01-20 22:27:57.824  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2024-01-20 22:27:58.618  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2024-01-20 22:27:58.619  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2024-01-20 22:27:58.619  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2024-01-20 22:27:58.619  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2024-01-20 22:27:58.619  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2024-01-20 22:27:58.619  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2024-01-20 22:27:58.619  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2024-01-20 22:28:00.825  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused stacktrace=com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
        at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:196)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:167)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1101)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1014)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:441)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:283)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:279)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:66)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:295)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:374)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:376)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:179)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:127)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:115)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:485)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2c22310.getEurekaClient(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:937)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:423)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
        at com.mockup.mockup.MockupApplication.main(MockupApplication.java:10)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
        ... 77 more

2024-01-20 22:28:00.826  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2024-01-20 22:28:01.019  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MOCKUP-TEST/mockup-69c7855f5b-8phdb:mockup-test - was unable to refresh its cache! This periodic background refresh will be retried in 30 seconds. status = Cannot execute request on any known server stacktrace = com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

As you can see Eureka client is running for some reason. I can't find why. Do you know  what might be the reason. It should be disabled.

Comment: Can you add pod template? it looks like tomcat listen on `8080` trying to connect to port `8761`

Comment: I use helm chart for pod deployment.

Comment: Is it your or it it public? can you add it?

Comment: You can try change [this port](https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml#L8) to `8080`

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/tree/master/helm_chart/mockup-chart

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your yaml file for Kubernetes you are not providing port so default(`8080`) is used, also `eureka` is not set as in your file for local development.

As you file looks like this

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: application-mockup-configuration
data:
  application-mockup-configuration.yml: |
    init:
      message: "Test message loaded from default external application-mockup-configuration.yml file !!!!!!!!!!!"
    spring:
      application:
        name: mockup-test
      jackson:
        default-property-inclusion: non_null
      jmx:
        enabled: false
```

When you change it to (added `server` and `eureka`):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: application-mockup-configuration
data:
  application-mockup-configuration.yml: |
    init:
      message: "Test message loaded from default external application-mockup-configuration.yml file !!!!!!!!!!!"
    spring:
      application:
        name: mockup-test
      jackson:
        default-property-inclusion: non_null
      jmx:
        enabled: false
    server:
      port: 8761
    eureka:
      client:
        registerWithEureka: false
        fetchRegistry: false
```

It will work

Comment: The error message is not shown but this means that application.yml file located into the jar file and the configuration file from the helm chart are not merged which is a problem. As far as I know they should be.

Comment: Looks like external file overrides the default  application.yml file located into the jar file

Comment: Yes, right now I found [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20745), someone had this issue but kind of opposite direction. Checking other links there, it looks like those two locations are exclusive, but docs say it shouldn't be

Comment: I configured `spring.config.additional-location` now it's working fine.